# Which PGP fingerprint to share/publish as my digital identity?

Tags: gnupg, pgp, openpgp

The primary secret key should be stored offline and only be used for creating/signing keys.

There will be at least two secret keys: one primary key or subkey for signing, and one subkey for encryption; there might be a third key for authorisation.

Any of these keys has a fingerprint, which would be displayed in either full length, long format, or deprecated/insecure short format.

Files will be **signed** with my primary key or subkey for signing, and show the respective fingerprint; that’s still the easy-to-grasp part.

Files will be **encrypted** with the subkey for encryption, though, and therefore show a different fingerprint and not the one of my primary key or subkey for signing; that’s rather confusing to me.

*Note: And also subkeys could be revoked, and or changed in time to come.*

**Which fingerprint could/should be shared/published as my digital identity?**

Comment: Most if not all user interfaces for PGP, commandline and graphical, normally show the keyid (which is the 'long' or 'short' _portion_ of the fingerprint) for the primary aka master key, even though subkey(s) is(are) used for (some or all of) the actual cryptography and their ids can often be teased out if you put a lot of effort into it -- which most people won't. Thus **the primary id is what you should show or give to humans**.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you for your comment. After encrypting some file with the encryption subkey of my keypair, `gpg --list-packets $file` shows the fingerprint of the encryption subkey, **not** the primary key or signing subkey which I would publish/share with others; when others look up the fingerprint on e.g. my website, then these two fingerprints don’t match.